# Passing CLI objects in functions that modify them

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am struggling to figure out this type of code:

```
void changeString (String^% str)
{
    str = "New String";
}
```

Why do I need to pass a tracking reference to a handle to the object? This is so irritating.
Why is the handle not enough, a handle is similar to c++ pointer, so why not...

Thanks

Comment: Is this the case only for String, or I will have to do this for all types of objects, if I want to modify them in a function?

Comment: The complaint is a bit silly, references are a basic programming concept.  You could use a StringBuilder instead.  A very obvious way to make this particular snippet cleaner is to *return* the new string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is no different in spirit from this C++ code:

```
void reset_foo(Foo * & p)
{
    p = new Foo;   // leeks, neeps and tatties
}
```

Usage:

```
Foo * p;
reset_foo(p);
```

This in turn is just a particular case of the general notion of passing references:

```
void set_int(int & n) { n = 10; }

int a;
set_int(a);
assert(a == 10);
```

Comment: Yes I figured this out. So in that case the main thing I miss in the puzzle is to understand that String is immutable reference type as Joe Gauterin said. Then the question is, are all CLI types immutable reference types? Will I have to pass them all in that manner if I want to change them in a function?

Comment: @user2381422: What do you mean by "immutable reference"? You mean the object is immutable? You can write your own CLI classes, and they don't have to be immutable. Maybe `String` is, but that's a design choice.

Comment: So how do I then pass objects to functions, where the objects will be modified inside the functions? I still have to pass them as MyClass^%, that is a tracking reference to a handle?

Comment: @user2381422: just as a handle should be fine if you want to (and can) mutate the object directly.

Comment: @user2381422: If you want to modify an object inside a function you only need a handle. If you instead want to make the handle refer to a different object you need a tracking reference. Most reference types are mutable - `String` is an exception.